# iwlwifi VS NetworkManager

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, iwlwifi

I have an `iwlwifi` module installed and used as driver on my Lenovo ThinkPad s440 (Ubuntu 15.04). I also use NetworkManager for GUI setup which works perfectly till some point. But I found out that in one wifi spot I get two IP addresses connections. I.e. I can connect via lan cable to the same network and it works fine, but `wlan0` shows connection and signal and packages transmission but no actual data transfer. I'm not a network guy, so do not completely understand network configuration, but here's the input:

lspci -k

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
  Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260
  Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

dmesg | grep iwlwifi

```
774:[   13.321400] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.17.12.0 op_mode iwlmvm
775:[   13.885174] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wireless N 7260, REV=0x144
776:[   13.885246] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
777:[   13.885484] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
977:[   43.279857] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
978:[   43.280100] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
```

iwconfig wlan0

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"AhoyWatt"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 7C:0E:CE:3C:3B:90   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=26/70  Signal level=-84 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:4  Invalid misc:77   Missed beacon:0
```

iw dev wlan0 link

```
Connected to 7c:0e:ce:3c:3c:38 (on wlan0)
  SSID: AhoyWatt
  freq: 2412
  RX: 1744900 bytes (9092 packets)
  TX: 11702 bytes (41 packets)
  signal: -32 dBm
  tx bitrate: 1.0 MBit/s

  bss flags:  short-slot-time
  dtim period:  2
  beacon int: 100
```

Could anyone suggest what's the problem why I can connect via cable and can't do this via wifi module exactly at this wifi spot ? One guy told me that I have two IP addresses assigned at the same time by iwl and NetworkManager and this is the conflict, but I do not understand why and what's the problem.